Run the code where given path have multiple subfolders and same code to be apply for cropping images using PIL python
I have a 5000 multiple folders in one folder i.e test, each folder has 2-3 images, I need to crop the images, currently my code is for applying single folder for crop the images, is there any alternate option where multiple folders can apply for the same code.
Here is my code
from PIL import Image
import os.path, sys
path = r"D:\test"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

def crop():
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)         
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            im = Image.open(fullpath)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
            imCrop = im.crop((80, 270, 4000, 3000)) 
            imCrop.save(f + 'Cropped.jpg', "JPEG")
crop()



Just add another for loop?

@jeyekomen, on which line need to add.

Have you considered a recursive glob?

No idea about Glob function, can you guide how to use this

You could use os.walk to recursively walk through all dirs:
from PIL import Image
import os

root_dir = r"D:\test"

def crop_image(image_path):
    try:
        with Image.open(image_path) as im:
            im_crop= im.crop((80,270,4000,3000)) 
            file_name,ext =os.path.splitext(image_path)
            cropped_image = file_name+'_Cropped.jpg'
            im_crop.save(cropped_image,"JPEG")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error {image_path}:{e}")

def crop_images_in_folders(root_folder):
    for folder_name,subfolders,filenames in os.walk(root_folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            full_image_path = os.path.join(folder_name,filename)
            if filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg','.jpeg', '.png')):
                crop_image(full_image_path)


crop_images_in_folders(root_dir)


A recursive glob is probably what you want for this. You could also consider  using multiprocessing if the cropping process is CPU-intensive.
Something like this:
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from sys import stderr

SOURCE_DIR = Path("D:\\test")

def process(p: Path) -> None:
    try:
        Image.open(p) \
            .crop((80, 270, 4000, 3000)) \
            .save(p.parent / (p.stem + "Cropped.jpg"), "JPEG")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=stderr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, SOURCE_DIR.rglob("*.jpg"))


raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed

@Kiran If you're getting an OSError then you haven't copied this answer exactly. Probably an indentation error
